# Can I use esri-leaflet together with arcgis api?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, leaflet, esri-leaflet

I am not sure I have understood the co-existence of arcgis javascript api with the  [esri-leaflet library](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet).

Can I use leaflet together with the javascript api.

For example can I have my map built with the javascript api (new esri.Map(...) )
and then add an L.esri.Dynamic layer ?

If not, I suppose I will have to choose which of the two different paths I want to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

esri leaflet is an alternative to the ArcGIS API for JavaScript, not something that makes much sense to try and combine.

L.esri.[DynamicMapLayer](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/dynamic-map-layer.html) provides comparable functionality (within Leaflet) for loading dynamic map services published to ArcGIS Server to the class 'esri/layers/[ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html)' in the JSAPI

please check out the esri leaflet [FAQ](https://github.com//Esri/esri-leaflet/wiki/FAQ#will-esri-leaflet-replace-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript) for more info.